# Name collision between c++ library namespace and C linux function

Tags: c++, linux, namespaces, name-collision

The Linux `<ncurses.h>` header defines the function [`meta`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/meta), and the C++ metaprogramming library [`meta`](https://github.com/ericniebler/meta) puts all its code in the global namespace `meta`.

How can I use both in the same C++ program (not necessarily the same TU but that would be nice)? Is there a way to work around the name collision?

I can think of two brittle workarounds, but they are easy to break:

- Workaround A:

  ```
   namespace linux {
   #include <ncurses.h>
   }  // namespace linux
   using linux::max_align_t;  // ncurses assumes it is in the global namespace
   #include <meta/meta.hpp>
  ```

  compiles but will probably fail to link since the `ncurses` symbols are expected in the global namespace.
- Workaround B:

  ```
  #include <ncurses.h>
  namespace cpp {
  #include <meta/meta.hpp>
  }  // namespace cpp
  ```

  is very brittle since it will only work as long as the `meta` library doesn't assume that any of its symbols are in the global namespace. That is, if the library needs to disambiguate internally a symbol and uses `::meta::symbol_name` for that, this approach will break.

Comment: Approach A won't work, as you know yourself. Approach B might work - you can try. But I'd first try as hard as I can to see if I can separate those two libraries so that no single unit of transaltion uses both.

Comment: Try writing a wrapper for one so you never include both headers in the same translation unit and hope the linker is fine with it.

Comment: @NathanOliver `<ncurses.h>` has a function called meta, while `<meta/meta.hpp>` has a namespace called `meta` within the global namespace, so the function name clashes with the namespace's name.

Comment: Remember that namespace names is only a *compiler* thing. Once the object files has been generated there exists no "namespaces" any more. So translation-unit separation is definitely the way to go. It's probably a good design decision as well.

Comment: The `meta` library is one open source header right? How about just changing the namespace name?

Comment: @Barry That will work, if the library is a header-only library, or the OP is building the library from source. At least it will work until it's time to update the library. It might be some work getting all the search-replace right though.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Just [two headers](https://github.com/ericniebler/meta/tree/master/include/meta) (if you exclude the tests).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Re: "only a compiler thing". I'm sure the namespace goes into the mangling, at least in Visual Studio. So the linker sees it, in a way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest workaround C: Isolate your code such that the `meta` library use and the `ncurses` use are in separate translation units in your project. This way in any particular translation unit there isn't one symbol being used as both a namespace and a global function.

Comment: Since meta is a header only library it is probably easier to write a wrapper around `<ncurses.h>` that only includes this header in its cpp file.

Comment: @gnzlbg If you look around a little I'm sure there already are C++ wrappers for the ncurses library that you can use. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg not needed: ncurses already includes c++ bindings (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544280/c-wrappers-for-ncurses)

Answer (score 1):

I'm reasonably certain that neither A nor B will actually work, at least as given. You've pointed toward one of them, but I think it's the less likely of the two. There are two problems that are basically mirror images of each other.

If the code in `ncurses` is declared as `extern "C"` (typical for many C libraries that have been made to work with C++), surrounding them with a namespace won't actually work--an `extern "C"` declaration basically ignores namespaces and declares a function in the global namespace. The namespace won't change much of anything, and you'll still have a collision.

If the content of `<ncurses.h>` is not declared `extern "C"`, then you'll run into the problem you cited: the library is built with functions in the global namespace, but the client code is seeing definitions for code in the `linux`  namespace. Since the namespace affects the mangled name (that's how it prevents a collision) your code won't be able to link. All the `linux::*` functions will show up as unresolved externals.

To make this work, you need to assure that none of the library code is declared `extern "C"`, and specify the namespace *inside* the header (and the library source files), and re-compile the library with these declarations, so the library and its client code agree on the namespace where that code resides.